# Is this a good way to get the height of a binary tree?

Tags: python, algorithm, search, tree, binary-tree

I am not a CS student so this is not homework. I am trying to learn these things myself but I want to make sure I am not developing bad habits along the way.

Basically, I have a classic binary tree, and I want to calculate the height (or depth) of the tree.

What I mean by height is like this image:

[image: this]

The height of this tree is 3.

This is the python I came up with:

```
def height(node):

    #highest one of these two will be returned
    i_left = 0
    i_right = 0

    #if has left, increment and recursively move left
    if node.hasleft():
        i_left += height(node.left)
        i_left += 1

    #if has right, increment and recursively move right
    if node.hasright():
        i_right += height(node.right)
        i_right += 1

    #return the higher value
    if i_right <= i_left:
        return i_left    
    return i_right
```

This solution works, and I kinda like it because it's simple and doesn't have a lot of abstract things to work your head around. However, I do wonder if this is the way it should be done. Is there any way it could be improved, or is there a more accepted way of implementing a height function?

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong. On a tree with just one node, it'll say the height is 0.

Comment: The last part can be simply `return max(i_right, i_left)`

Comment: Can you share the rest of the class/code?

Comment: You have to visit every leaf in the tree and count how many levels it took to get to each one — no way around that. What you have looks basically OK except for a little optimization.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I guess rather than height what I really want is max level. Hence the levels are starting from 0. I'm thinking if I ever wanna display it with a 2d list it will make it easier if it's in array form (at least, I think so lol)

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica That's not wrong; it's a very normal definition of height. See for example NIST's Dictionary of Algorithms and Data Structures: https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/height.html

Comment: @kaya3 If a single-node tree is considered to be height 0, then you'd have to also consider the tree in the picture to be height 2, but it's indicated as being height 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code only adds 1 to the height of the left or right nodes if there are child nodes. You need to add 1 for the current node even if there are no children. So it shouldn't be in the `if` blocks.

```
def height(node):

    #if has left, recursively move left
    if node.hasleft():
        i_left = height(node.left)
    else:
        i_left = 0

    #if has right, recursively move right
    if node.hasright():
        i_right = height(node.right)
    else:
        i_right = 0

    #return the higher value, plus 1 for the current node.
    return 1 + max(i_left, i_right)
```

Comment: Don't worry, I should have clarified but I am actually intending to start from 0. Max is a great edit though.

I'm confused though, where is it being incremented? Am I missing something?

Comment: Your diagram clearly says it starts at 1. My code increments in the `return` statement with `1 +`.

Comment: @Barmar: A "tree" consisting of exactly one node (i.e. the "root") has a height of zero, no?

Comment: Not in your picture. You have the number `1` next to the root node.

Comment: Nevermind, I ran though it a few times and I see it now. Also, sorry about the numbers, I wrote them on a random image and wasn't really thinking. Didn't mean to make it sound like you don't know what you're doing or anything.

Comment: If you do want it to start at `0`, you can move the addition back into the `if` blocks. Just write `i_left = 1 + height(node.left)` and similar for `i_right`.

Comment: It's normal to define the height of a tree as the number of edges in the longest path from the root node to a leaf; in that case a tree with just one node (the root) has a height of zero because it has no edges. The NIST's Dictionary of Algorithms and Data Structures defines height this way, for example: https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/height.html

Answer (score 4):

The key idea of your algorithm is sensible and correct; you have to make recursive calls on the left and right subtrees, and add 1.

Assuming your `node.left` and `node.right` attributes are `None` when there is no left or right subtree respectively, the function can be simplified by making just one check to see if the current node exists, instead of two checks to see if each of its children exist. This means the input is sometimes `None`, in which case the correct return value is -1 so that a leaf node's height will be 0.

```py
def height(node):
    if node is None:
        return -1
    else:
        i_left = height(node.left)
        i_right = height(node.right)
        return 1 + max(i_left, i_right)
```

Or if you are a fan of one-liners:

```py
def height(node):
    return -1 if node is None else 1 + max(height(node.left), height(node.right))
```

This follows [the usual definition](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/height.html) of height as the number of edges in a longest path from the root, so that the height of a tree with one node is 0. If you define height as the number of nodes in that path, so that the height of a one-node tree is 1, then just change the base case to `return 0` instead of `return -1`.

Comment: My favorite is the one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Your overall algorithm is the best way to do it.

You have no way of knowing which branch will be the longest, so the only way to do it would be to check each path and find the maximum. Your recursive structure seems like a pretty classic one for a tree structure!